# Why does wildcard for jar execution not work in docker CMD?

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

I have a `Dockerfile` with the following `CMD` to start my spring boot app:

```
FROM java:8-jre
# ...
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/file*.jar"]
```

When I try to start a container from the created image I get:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /app/file*.jar
```

But when I override the `CMD` while starting the container and execute the command in the container everything works fine:

```
docker run -it <imageId> bash
root@<containerId>:/app# java -jar /app/file*.jar
<spring boot app starts...>
```

Is it possible to use wildcards with `java -jar` command using docker CMDs? 
Please don't tell me not to use wildcards. I want to use it cause of reasons ;-)

**Update**
Based on the answer I was able to fix it:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "java -jar /app/file*.jar"]
```

Comment: `CMD java -jar /app/file*.jar` is roughly the same and a bit more direct.

Comment: What are the reasons for using wildcards?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The jar file name contained the version and I did not want to adapt the Dockerfile every time or use a `build-arg`. A wildcard seemed to be a simple way to avoid both.

Comment: Strip the version number when copying the jar file into the container

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This kind of asterisk expansion is done by the command line processor - the shell - and you circumvent that by invoking java directly.

Much the same way as commands should be invoked with "CMD /C" under Windows to get full treatment.

Invoke `/bin/sh` instead.

Comment: Also you may want to consider deploying a launcher script handling all these things along with your jar file.  For maven builds this is typically done with the appassembler-maven-plugin

Answer (score 5):

`CMD java -jar /app/file*.jar` worked for me

Comment: Yup. `CMD java -cp "lib/*" com.mydomain.Main` works for me. "docker ps" shows that it runs a shell: "/bin/sh -c 'java -c..."

Comment: @ccleve in that case the asterisk is understood and processed by the JVM.