# Unable to access jarfile when starting a container

Tags: docker, jar

I'm trying to build my app within docker and trying to start it. Below is my docker file,

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7

MAINTAINER "Kannan Ramamoorthy"

RUN mkdir /var/myapp

WORKDIR /var/myapp

COPY . .

RUN ./gradlew build -x test

EXPOSE 8080

RUN ls  /var/myapp/build/libs/myapp*.jar

RUN whoami

USER root

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "build/libs/myapp*.jar"]
```

Some observations,

- The `whoami` prints `root`.
- And `ls` prints the file.
- If I change the entry point to something else say `"ping", "google.com"`, I'm able to get into server and start the jar.
- I tried adding `CMD ["-start"]` at the end, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521926/2046462)(Though I didn't get it why yet).
- I tried giving the absolute path of the `jar` stillsame error.

None of those works. Any suggestion on fix and why its happening this way?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem is that wildcard card doesn't work with the Entrypoint statement of Dockerfile, the solution and reason for the problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428013/why-does-wildcard-for-jar-execution-not-work-in-docker-cmd)